# Grouping questions that go together

Tags: feature-request

Is there a way to post a series of related questions? My use case is to post a set of puzzles, the answers to which form a meta puzzle (in the style of the MIT mystery hunt & various other puzzle hunts). If not, this is a feature request.

Comment: We could also use this feature to run full-blown puzzle hunts if we wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

This has been done in the past just by [including a unique word or phrase](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) in the title that makes the puzzles easy to search for.  You can then create a hyperlink that goes directly to the search, showing a list of related puzzles.

People have also just [put links directly to the other puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/18512) into the puzzle description.

I don't know what is the best or most appropriate way of doing this, but these are ways it has been done in the past.  There is no official way of grouping puzzles.